# Why errno can set to zero by scanf?(when enter "ctrl+D")

Tags: c, linux

The manual tells us:errno is never set to zero by any system call or library function. But I want to know, Why errno can set  to zero by scanf in following codes?(when scanf:enter the"ctrl+D")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    errno = 5;
    printf("errno:%d\n",errno);
    if (scanf("%d", &i) < 1)
        perror("scanf");
    printf("errno:%d\n",errno);
    printf("i:%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't change , when I ran this code `errno` kept it's original value (5)

Comment: when you enter "ctrl+D", errno will be set to 0.

Comment: What operating system (including version number), compiler (including version), and compiler switches are you using? Are you sure this is exactly the code being executed (e.g., the code in the editor was saved to the file before compiling)? If the second `printf` shows zero, it may be a bug in your C implementation.

Comment: The OP reports in a comment that this is with GCC 4.4.7 20120313, Red Hat 4.4.7-3. Can anybody reproduce with that?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with GCC 4.7.2 on Debian 4.7.2-5.

Answer (score 3):

I can find the following code in the [glibc implementation of `vfscanf()`](https://github.com/heyc/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfscanf.c), (line 589-607 in the linked file, as of the time of writing) which the implementation of `scanf()` calls:

```
if (skip_space || (fc != L_('[') && fc != L_('c')
                         && fc != L_('C') && fc != L_('n')))
  {
    /* Eat whitespace. */
    int save_errno = errno;
    __set_errno (0);
    do
      /* We add the additional test for EOF here since otherwise
         inchar will restore the old errno value which might be
         EINTR but does not indicate an interrupt since nothing
         was read at this time. */
      if (__builtin_expect ((c == EOF || inchar () == EOF)
                             && errno == EINTR, 0))
         input_error ();
    while (ISSPACE (c));
    __set_errno (save_errno);
    ungetc (c, s);
    skip_space = 0;
  }
```

`input_error()` is `#define`d as:

```
#define input_error()         do {     
                          errval = 1; 
                          if (done == 0) done = EOF;
                          goto errout; 
                        } while (0)
```

where `errout` is the label for the cleanup code at the end.

So it looks like `errno` is getting set to `0` prior to the `inchar()` call, and the old value is later replaced, leaving `errno` unchanged. But if an error occurs and that `if` statement executes (notably, if `inchar()` evaluates to `EOF`, which is what is happening in this case), it looks like the code to reset `errno` to its original value may be being skipped. That being said, the condition will only be true if `errno == EINTR` and therefore not zero, which certainly doesn't appear to be the case, here, so it may have nothing to do with this code, but this is only place I can see `errno` being set to `0`. `inchar()` itself does mess around with `errno`, as the comment suggests, and can set `errno` to `inchar_errno`, which is initialized to `0` on line 223, so it's also possible there's some other execution path where `inchar_errno` is not updated but gets assigned to `errno` anyway.

Comment: That code also contains `errno = inchar_errno` as part of the `inchar()` macro, and it looks like there is an exit that does not restore it, but I am not going to trace the uses of this code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. You should [report it](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/). (That page is for GCC bugs. GCC only supplies parts of the standard library; I am not sure whether `scanf` is part of GCC. The Red Hat bug-reporting system is [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/).)

Per C 2011 (N1570) 7.5 3: “The value of errno in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of errno in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function.”

N1570 is not the official version of the standard, but it is close, and the official version of the 1999 standard had the same specification without the thread aspect: “The value of errno is zero at program startup, but is never set to zero by any library function.”

Comment: LOL a bug found after 14 years? (not saying you're wrong, I just find it funny)

Comment: There are [618 open bug tickets](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=&limit=0&no_redirect=1&product=glibc&query_format=specific) on glibc as we speak.